# MessageComposeResult is sent even if the message send failed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sms

I am using MFMessageComposeViewController to send sms within my app. Everything is correct until i try to get the result of the operation. Actually the Message sending failed as It can be seen in the SMS native app (I have no service in the sim card), but I get MessageComposeResultSent in - (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result.

Have you ever gone though this? Could we get a real assert that the sms has been properly sent?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a snippet from the *MessageComposeResult* struct's discussion in MFMessageComposeViewController.h :

> Typically *MessageComposeResultSent*
>   will be sent, but
>   *MessageComposeResultFailed* will be
>   sent in the case of failure. **Send may
>   only be interpreted as a successful
>   queueing of the message for later
>   sending. The actual send will occur
>   when the device is able to send.**

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems a bit odd that you couldn't discriminate queueing and sending. I will just have to alert that to the user.

Comment: @toupper Where you able to investigate when MessageComposeResultFailed fires? Because currently I am facing the same. Even if I put the phone on AIRPLANE MODE ON or DISABLE the SIM still I get MessageComposeResultSent